# Indy 10, could not load OpenSSL library on Windows 11

Tags: windows, openssl, c++builder, indy10, c++builder-xe5

I am building my VCL application on RAD Studio XE5 and I am using Indy 10 library (IndyCore190.bpl) with libeay32 and ssleay32 (1.0.2u) to connect to the server.

Application works on Windows 10 and is able to connect to the server using TLS1.2. Now I am trying same application on Windows 11 and Indy is giving me error as 'could not load ssl library'.

```
IdTCPClient->Connect();
```

Could you please suggest what configuration change required on Windows 11, so that my application can load ssl libraries.

Regards,
Nilesh

Comment: Are you using the version of Indy that shipped with XE5? Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of Indy yet? What does Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` and `OpenSSLVersion()` functions report when the error occurs?

Comment: WhichFailedToLoad() gave me error - "Failed to load c:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication\libeay32.dll."  OpenSSLVersion() returned with null.  I am calling IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(strOpenSSLPath) and LoadOpenSSLLibrary() before making connect() call.   Indy libraries are upgraded ones and not from XE5 installation.  How to check which version of Indy libraries I have?

Comment: That error message means Indy is unable to load `libeay32.dll` into memory. Does that DLL actually exist at that path? Is there a corresponding `ssleay32.dll` file in the same folder? Are you using a copy of the DLLs that depend on other DLLs (such as the MSVC runtime), and if so are those DLLs also present? Where did you get your OpenSSL DLLs from exactly?

Comment: Yes, both libeay32 and ssleay32 exists in same folder. Both dlls are built from OpenSSL source(openssl.org). And same installation works on my Window 10. But during my test on Windows 11 it is giving me this error.

Comment: this is no longer an Indy issue, it is an OS issue. There are only so many reasons for the OS to fail to load a DLL. Most commonly - missing file, missing dependency, or wrong bitness. Is your app compiled as 32bit or 64bit? Are the DLLs compiled as 32bit or 64bit? Which version of OpenSSL did you build? Have you tried using any OpenSSL DLLs that you *did not* build yourself (for instance, ones from Indy's [OpenSSL-Binaries repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries))?

Comment: Replacing libeay32 and ssleay32 from Indys OpenSSL repo resolved the issue. Thanks Remy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try openssl-1.0.2u-i386-win32.zip form https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries. That fixed it for me. Copy the two dll files to the exe directory.